# How to render an animation in and then render it out after it is done playing?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

My react app has tasks for the user to complete. Every time the user completes a task, the state will update and an animation will be played.

I want the animation to only appear upon completion of task, and disappear as soon as the animation is over. How would I do this? I was thinking of just having a state (ie. playAnimation) have that set to false until the task is complete and then set that to true. Then inside the return() I'd have a conditional statement to only render the animation in when the state is true. I would use a setTimeOut to have the state changed back to false at the end of the animation. But I find this solution to be very inefficient.

Is there another way I can do this?

```
function onTaskComplete() {
  //render in animation and then render it out once it finishes playing
}
```

Comment: How are you making/displaying the animation?

Comment: Im using the react-lottie component, sorry I should have specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something you could implement. Without seeng more of your code it will be hard to give you *exactly* what you want.

Firstly, here is a simple animation function that emits events. You can use these events to communicate from your animation code to React UI code.

```js
function animate(from, to, duration) {
  const events = {};

  // Basic event emitter, used to communicate from this function to React
  const emitter = {
    on(event, fn) {
      if (!events.hasOwnProperty(event)) {
        events[event] = [];
      }
      events[event].push(fn);
      let index = events.length - 1;
      return () => events[event].splice(index, 1);
    },
    emit(event, data) {
      (events[event] || []).forEach((fn) => fn(data));
    },
  };

  const startTime = Date.now();
  const map = (n, x1, y1, x2, y2) => Math.min(Math.max(((n - x1) * (y2 - x2)) / (y1 - x1) + x2, x2), y2);

  let frame;
  (function update() {
    frame = requestAnimationFrame(update);
    const delta = Date.now() - startTime;
    const value = map(delta, 0, duration, from, to);
    emitter.emit("tick", value);
  })();

  return emitter;
}
```

Here's how you would implement this function into React.

```js
function Task(props) {
  const [complete, setComplete] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!complete) {
      return;
    }

    // Start the animation when this task is complete
    const animation = animate(0, 100, 2000);
    const tickListener = animation.on("tick", (value) => {
      // Animation has updated, do something with the value
      console.log(value);
    });
    const endListener = animation.on("end", () => {
      // Animation has now ended, do something else.
      console.log("Animation ended.");
    });
    // Remove events
    return () => {
      tickListener();
      endListener();
    };
  }, [complete]);

  return null; // Render UI
}
```

This will start the animation when the task is marked as `completed` and will fire `tick` when the animation value changes (use this to update something). Once the animation has ended, it will emit `end`, you can use this to execute any additional code, e.g. reverse the animation.

Comment: little bit of tweaking to match my original code and it works great! Thank you!